# Javascript math parser library

Tags: javascript, math, string-parsing

Is there a good math parser in Javascript? I want to be able to parse something like:

```
LOG(3.14)+5^2+POW(2,LN(X*2,Y))
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is this for a job? If not I would use this as an opportunity to write my own.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a brand new initiative:

http://mathjs.org

Comes with an extensive and easy to use parser which also supports assignment and usage of variables and functions like in your example expression.

Answer (score 3):

Use this one.  It defined an "operator" object that lets you define your own operators.

http://jsfromhell.com/classes/math-processor

Warning:  it uses `with`.  If you don't know why that's dangerous, find out before using this code in anything critical.  Alternately, you could just re-write it without `with`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about `with` because of this: `{p: MathProcessor.prototype}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [nerdamer](https://github.com/jiggzson/nerdamer)

```js
var result = nerdamer('log(3.14)+5^2+2^(log(X*2)/log(Y))').evaluate();
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = result.text();
```

```html
<script src="http://nerdamer.com/js/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I found it by chance and I have [something to help](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/). Not as complete as mathjs, but useful and fast.