# Sum 2 numbers in a text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik controls in an ASP.Net application for invoice entry.

I'm looking for the ability to enter multiple amounts in one numeric field and add them together, just like in Quickbooks.

Keystrokes:

<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>TAB or ENTER</kbd>

adds values to 3.57 and jumps to the next field.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Telerik controls here, but a JS math parser might be just as good in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936730/javascript-math-parser-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices here:

1. Write your own method to parse the formula (more complicated than it sounds, even if you think it sounds complicated).
2. Use an pre-written math parser. [This](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/math-processor) is a decent one.
3. Use `eval()`.

**NOTE:** Should you choose option #3, exercise extreme caution and do your research first. `eval()` can leave your application open to all sorts of nasty code injection.

Comment: Code injection bad, however the Eval() route can be made much safer by first RegEx-ing the text string to only allowable characters.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to build a lexical parser for in-fix (rather than prefix) notation. There should be plenty of examples around - it's a pretty standard concept used on a lot of degree courses.

As to whether it's a good idea to do this (I assume client-side)...